# ExpandarHeader with TextBlock

Tags: .net, wpf, expander

Text Block is not working in Expander.Header
I get System.Window.Control.TextBlod

```
<Expander Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="expMainInstructions"
                        MaxHeight="400"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpanderHelp}">
```

This works

```
<Expander.Header>khjasdf</Expander.Header>
```

This does **not** work 
I also tried Expander.Header.Content

```
<Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock>Instructions</TextBlock>
</Expander.Header>
```

Comment: What is `ExpanderHelp` style? Do you change `Template`? If yes what do you use to present `Header`? Is it `TextBlock` or `ContentPresenter`?

Comment: @dkozl That was the fix. If you will post as and answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not publish `ExpanderHelp` style but problem you're experiencing would suggest that you created custom `Template` and use `TextBlock` instead of `ContentPresenter` to present `Header`. If that's the case anything your put into `Header` will be converted to a `string`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <!-- .... -->
    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
    <!-- .... -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes there was a HeaderTemplate in the Style that was breaking it